# Slightly confused about whether printf in the yash shell is a built-in command or not

Tags: posix, printf, shell-builtin, yash

The `yash` shell has a `printf` built-in, [according to its manual](https://yash.osdn.jp/doc/_printf.html).

However, this is what I see in a `yash` shell with default configuration:

```
$ command -v printf
/usr/bin/printf
$ type printf
printf: a regular built-in at /usr/bin/printf
```

Is `printf` a built-in in this shell or not?  The result is similar for a number of other supposedly built-in utilities that are also available as external commands.

As a comparison, in `pdksh` (`ksh` on OpenBSD, where `printf` is *not* a built-in):

```
$ command -v printf
/usr/bin/printf
$ type printf
printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

And in `bash` (where `printf` *is* a built-in):

```
$ command -v printf
printf
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
```

Comment: It's a built-in -- a *regular*, not a *special* built-in. If you're confused about the difference between *special* and *regular* built-ins, or behavior mandated by the standard (see [command search and execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) 1.e.i.a) -- which requires that a binary should exist in `PATH` in order for a *regular* built-in to be executed -- then please make your question about that.

Comment: @mosvy This was a detail of the standard that was unknown to me. If you want to turn that into an answer, I'd be happy.  I don't think I would need to update the question for this to be an appropriate answer, as I was unaware of this particular detail.  Or I'll write it myself later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `yash` shell *does* have, and does use, a built-in version of `printf` (and other utilities).  It just happens to be very pedantically POSIX compliant in the way it formulates the result of the `command -v` and `type` commands.

[As mosvy comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496259/slightly-confused-about-whether-printf-in-the-yash-shell-is-a-built-in-command-o#comment912715_496259), the POSIX standard requires that a regular built-in command be available as an external command in `$PATH` for the built-in version of the command to be executed.

This is [the relevant text from the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> Command Search and Execution
>
> If a simple command results in a command name and an optional list of arguments, the following actions shall be performed:
>
> 1. If the command name does not contain any <slash> characters, the first successful step in the following sequence shall occur:
>
>    - a. If the command name matches the name of a special built-in utility, that special built-in utility shall be invoked.
>
>      [...]
>    - e. Otherwise, the command shall be searched for using the PATH environment variable as described in XBD Environment Variables :
>
>      - i. **If the search is successful:**
>
>        - a. **If the system has implemented the utility as a regular built-in or as a shell function, it shall be invoked at this point in the path search.**
>        - b. Otherwise, the shell executes the utility in a separate utility environment [...]
>            [...]
>      - ii. If the search is unsuccessful, the command shall fail with an exit status of 127 and the shell shall write an error message.
> 2. If the command name contains at least one <slash>, [...]

This means that the output of `command -v printf` signifies that the `printf` command *was* found in the search path, while the output of `type printf` adds to this that the command is a regular built-in.

Since the `printf` command was found in the search path, and since it's a regular built-in in the shell, *`yash` will call its built-in version of the command*. If the `printf` was *not* found in the path, and if the `yash` shell was running in POSIX-ly correct mode, an error would have been generated instead.

`yash` prides itself on being a very POSIX compliant shell, and this is also true if we look at [what POSIX says about `command -v`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/command.html):

> `-v`
>
> Write a string to standard output that indicates the pathname or command that will be used by the shell, in the current shell execution environment (see *Shell Execution Environment*), to invoke `command_name`, but do not invoke `command_name`.
>
> - Utilities, **regular built-in utilities**, `command_names` including a `<slash>` character, and any implementation-defined functions that are found using the `PATH` variable (as described in *Command Search and Execution*), **shall be written as absolute pathnames**.

Comment: Does anyone know why POSIX has this requirement for an external command to exist before running the built-in command?

Comment: @studog You may want to ask that as a separate new question, possibly referring to this answer and/or question.

Comment: Done: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496341/why-does-posix-require-certain-shell-built-ins-to-have-an-external-implementatio

Answer (score 6):

The Watanabe shell has three sorts of built-ins, described in detail in its manual.  All of the built-in commands are also listed there, but one has to infer that something is a "regular" built-in command from the *absence* of any note saying that the command is a "special" or a "semi-special" built-in.  Regular built-ins are unmarked.

`printf` is one such "regular" built-in.  In native mode it is *always* invoked, irrespective of whether there is an external command found by that name.

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin
$ printf
printf: this command requires an operand
$ type printf
printf: a regular built-in at /usr/bin/printf
$
$ PATH=/
$ printf
printf: this command requires an operand
$ type printf
printf: a regular built-in (not found in $PATH)
$
```

But when the `posixly-correct` shell option is set it is only a built-in if the external command can be found on the `PATH`.

```
$ set --posixly-correct
$
$ PATH=/usr/bin
$ printf
printf: this command requires an operand
$
$ PATH=/
$ printf
yash: no such command `printf'
$
```

This is actually conformant to what the Single Unix Specifiation says, and has said since at least 1997.

It differs from the Z shell, the 93 Korn shell, the Bourne Again shell, and the Debian Almquist shell, none of which either implement or document such behaviour for regular built-ins.  The Z shell, for example, documents that regular built-ins are *always* found, *before* the step that searches `PATH`.  So too does the Debian Almquist shell.  And that's what these shells all do, even if invoked as `sh` with their turn-on-POSIX options.

```
% /bin/exec -a sh zsh -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf is a shell builtin
zsh:printf:1: not enough arguments
% /bin/exec -a sh ksh93 -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf is a shell builtin
Usage: printf [ options ] format [string ...]
% /bin/exec -a sh bash --posix -c "PATH=/ type printf ; printf"
printf is a shell builtin
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
% /bin/exec -a sh dash -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf is a shell builtin
sh: 1: printf: usage: printf format [arg ...]
%
```

However, not running `printf` when it is not on the `PATH` is the behaviour of the PD Korn shell, the Heirloom Bourne shell, and the MirBSD Korn shell; because they do not have a `printf` built-in in the first place.  ☺

```
% /bin/exec -a sh `command -v ksh` -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf not found
sh: printf: not found
% /bin/exec -a sh `command -v oksh` -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf not found
sh: printf: not found
% /bin/exec -a sh `command -v jsh` -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf not found
sh: printf: not found
% /bin/exec -a sh mksh -c "PATH=/ ; type printf ; printf"
printf not found
sh: printf: not found
% ksh -c "type printf ; printf"
printf is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/printf
usage: printf format [arguments ...]
% oksh -c "type printf ; printf"
printf is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/printf
usage: printf format [arguments ...]
% jsh -c "type printf ; printf"
printf is hashed (/usr/bin/printf)
usage: printf format [arguments ...]
% mksh -c "type printf ; printf"
printf is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/printf
usage: printf format [arguments ...]
$
```

Comment: Good! Thanks for confirming and for adding the shell-specific bits to my knowledge!  I like this shell more already.