# How little work could `/usr/bin/cd` or `/usr/bin/wait` do and still be conforming?

Tags: command, posix

Can the executables with the same names as shell builtins get away with doing a lot less "work" than the shell builtins do? For instance, could the `fg` executable just exit abnormally immediately? Could the `wait` and `jobs` executable exit `0` if given no arguments and exit `1` otherwise?

So, on OS X, for instance, `/usr/bin/cd` and `/usr/bin/wait` are the following script(s):

```
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $
# This file is in the public domain.
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

This will really attempt to call the `sh` builtin with the same name as the file the script resides at, the same is true for a bunch of other utilities:

```
% grep -rl 'alias/generic[.]sh' /usr/bin
/usr/bin/umask
/usr/bin/unalias
/usr/bin/alias
/usr/bin/wait
/usr/bin/hash
/usr/bin/fc
/usr/bin/read
/usr/bin/type
/usr/bin/getopts
/usr/bin/bg
/usr/bin/fg
/usr/bin/cd
/usr/bin/command
/usr/bin/jobs
/usr/bin/ulimit
```

Based on [this question about the usefulness of an external `cd` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) and [one of its answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50060/) and [this question about `printf` in `yash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496259/slightly-confused-about-whether-printf-in-the-yash-shell-is-a-built-in-command-o), I think I understand the rationale for the existence of these commands in the first place, I'm just wondering if a select few of them could do less work than they currently do.

Comment: It would be uncommon to actually _use_ these external utilities as the builtins would be used first. It also looks like it could have unwanted consequences. For example, a script may use the external `cd` as a way of testing whether changing working directory _would work_, and then rely on the fact that an external `cd` would actually not change directory...